# How can I use subsets to separate stocks into groups in my R code as a constraint for a stock portfolio? Any thoughts would be much appreciated

Tags: r, optimization, stock, portfolio

```
assets <- c("1",  "2", "3", "4")
port_spec <- add.constraint(portfolio = port_spec, type = "group", groups = list(c(1, 2, 3), 4), group_labels = c("Grupa A", "Grupo B"), group_pos = c(2,1))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The code you proposed separates your vector of tickers in 2 groups: (`list(c(1, 2, 3), 4)`). One composed by symbols `c("1","2","3")` and one only composed by symbol `c("4")`. The division in groups is done based on the order you put the vector tickers. Group position determines the order in which the groups will be subjected to other constraints. If you need more than 2 groups you should act first on `list(c(1, 2, 3), 4,c(5,2))` (here the first group is made of `c("1","2","3")`, second: `c("4")`, third: `c("5","2")`.
It would be reasonable, when dividing in groups, to put a constraint to the maximum allocation, as well as the minimum allocation in each group. You can do it by adding to your code `group_min=c(X, Y, Q), group_max=c(W, K, L)`. The code would run anyway even without it since it sets default values though.

Below code as example:

```
port_spec = portfolio.spec(assets)
port_spec = add.constraint(port_spec, type ="weight_sum",
                min_sum = 0.99, max_sum = 1.01)
port_spec = add.constraint(port_spec, type = "long_only")
port_spec = add.objective(port_spec, type = "return", name  = "mean")
port_spec = add.objective(port_spec, type = "risk", name = "StdDev")
port_spec = add.constraint(port_spec, type = "group", groups = 
list(c(1,2,3),4),group_min=c(0, 0.4), 
                group_max=c(0.7, 0.5), group_labels = c("Grupa A", 
"Grupo B"), group_pos = c(1,2))
```

Then running `optimize.portfolio()` with DEoptim/random you will get the
optimized portfolio allocation given your group constraint.